# MVC Razor View Code Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on my first ASP.Net MVC Application . I am using Razor view and MVC version is 3.
I am getting data for my model from the database in some raw format. Then i do some processing on it like concating strings, format date columns using some linq queries. Everything on the data that i already have in the model class.

I wonder all this code execution is happening on server. I want to move this burden from my server to client machines, i want to pass this raw data to my view and then write code in view to do this loop things and formatting etc.

I just want to confirm if this is a good approach to move on and if this really release some burden from my server.

Thanks

Comment: you should follow pattern of fat models (viewmodes) thin controller. Views should not contain complex logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# or VB that is written in your view is not client side. It's still server side. It's used to manipulate the rendering of the HTML before being passed to the client.

You'd have to pass all your raw data then process it with JavaScript.

Performance of your app would depend on each client machine and therefore not be consistent between 2 users. Maintenance would be tricky as a result.

To cut a long story short I would not recommend it. Your server is most likely designed to handle load. It's the right place for this sort of thing.

And I'd also read up on server / client side code execution relations. Simply doing MVC is a good start. It naturally teaches you how the web works more so than using web forms.

Answer (score 1):

This may be pre-mature optimization.  I doubt whether a server would be bogged down performing simple things like string concatenation, formatting, etc.

I suggest you only focus on this if you run into performance issues; else it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Actually this is not just the formatting and caoncatnation, i just recursive loops and perform lots of linq queries on it and then generate the required data format, thats why i am asking this.

Comment: Well, linq cannot be performed on the browser so that isn't really an option :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused a View in MVC with browser HTML. You can have any C# code in View but not in browser. If you question is about doing business logic in View is then, read further.

MVC allows to plug any kind of view (mobile,desktop,web apps) to a controller. So view should not do any business logic else you will end up duplicating the business logic.

This [LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx) will help your understanding of MVC.

Data formatting in view not at all an issue but when you start implementing business logic in view that is the issue (I guess that's what you meant by use of linq in a View).

For instance inside a View, using linq on Model entities to loop through a collection and create a HTML table is perfectly all right, infact ViewModel should be tightly coupled to View.

[Trying hard not to be philosophical here but :)] In the end whatever architecture you use DO NOT limit yourself from thinking out of the box. Almost all projects use multiple patterns and most (good) developers solve business problems by unknowingly implementing a pattern. :)